# Expectation of the product of $2$ independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I would like some concrete examples of the expectation of the product of $2$ independent random variables. In other words $\mathbb{E}[fg]=\mathbb{E}[f]\cdot\mathbb{E}[g]$. I have learned about this in class but the teacher did not give any example and I have looked around for some with no luck. I would really appreciate it so that I can understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider a very simple example. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the values of rolling a die 2 times. We know that $\mathbb{E}(X_1) = \mathbb{E}(X_2) = 3.5$. One could then ask what is $\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2)$? We could of course determine the probability of every possible value of $X_1X_2$ individually and then compute the expectation in the normal way. Alternatively, we could simply note that the random variables are independent of each other and say $\mathbb{E}(X_1X_2) = \mathbb{E}(X_1)\mathbb{E}(X_2) = 3.5\cdot3.5=12.25.$

Answer (score 0):

Take *any* two *independent* random variables, $f,g$, then $\mathsf E(fg)=\mathsf E(f)\,\mathsf E(g)$.$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(fg) =&~ \mathsf E(\mathsf E(fg\mid f)) & \text{Law of Iterated Expectation}\\=&~ \mathsf E(f~\mathsf E(g\mid f)) & \text{}\\=&~ \mathsf E(f~\mathsf E(g)) & \text{because independence}\\=&~ \mathsf E(f)~\mathsf E(g) \end{align}$$

(Note: the converse is not necessarily true.   $\mathsf E(fg)=\mathsf E(f)\,\mathsf E(g)$ only implies that the two random variables are *uncorrelated*. )

---

Well, any two independent random variables will form an example.

Roll two fair die.   The expected value of the product of their independent results is:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(fg) =&~ \sum_{\phi=1}^6\sum_{\gamma=1}^6 \frac{\phi\gamma}{36} \\[1ex] =&~ \sum_{\phi=1}^6\frac{\phi}{6}\sum_{\gamma=1}^6 \frac{\gamma}{6} \\[1ex] =&~ \tfrac{3.5}{6}~\tfrac{3.5}{6}\\[1ex] =&~ \tfrac{49}{144}\end{align}$$

Take two independent uniform$(0;1)$ random variables. Then:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(fg) =&~ \int_0^1\int_0^1\phi\gamma\operatorname d \gamma\operatorname d \phi \\[1ex] =&~ \int_0^1 \phi \operatorname d \phi~\int_0^1 \gamma\operatorname d \gamma \\[1ex] =&~ \tfrac{1}{2}~\tfrac{1}{2}\\[1ex] =&~ \tfrac{1}{4}\end{align}$$

Comment: So, you're willing to assume that $f$ and $g$ being independent implies $E(g\mid f)=E(g)$ but not that $E(fg)=E(f)E(g)$? Alright.

Comment: Indeed. This seems a recurring theme of many answers on this site that conditional expectations would be more elementary than expectations. Odd.